# pointsize in png() is not working as expected

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to make a png in R where I can vary the resolution without changing the apparent height of the text and it is not working.

Here is my code

```
drawbox <- function(res, ps=12, textcex=1) {
  png(file="test.png",width=6,height=3, units="in", res=res, bg="transparent", pointsize=ps)
  plot(x=c(0,1),y=c(0,1),type="n",xaxs = 'i',yaxs = 'i',axes=FALSE)
  text(x=0.5, y=0.5, adj=c(0.5,0.5), labels="Some text", cex=textcex*6)
  dev.off()
}
```

then this makes a very different size of text

```
drawbox(res=300, ps=12, textcex=1)
```

than this

```
drawbox(res=100, ps=12, textcex=1)
```

but isn't that the point of the pointsize argument, that this doesn't happen?

Note: I need base graphics here, other packages lack the flexibility to allow me to make what I want to make.

If I mess around with that textcex parameter I can get things to work, but that's annoying.

Comment: `pointsize = 72 / res * ps`

Comment: Does that work for you? It doesn't work for me. If it works for you I'll include my session info.